# keepCurrentModels option for AggregatedView

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to load multiple models, following the steps described in this article: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

If you don't use the new AggregatedView class, you can use the option `keepCurrentModels: true` during `viewer.loadDocumentNode(...)` as described in the article.

However, when using the AggregatedView, I haven't been able to keep the already loaded models. This is because you don't load models using `loadDocumentNode(...)`.

I use the code provided in the sample on the site (https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e). How do I modify this code so I can load models after I already loaded initial models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `AggregatedView#show( bubble )` for other models you want to load after initials. The `AggregatedView#show` will apply the option `keepCurrentModels: true` while loading the new model according to the current design. On the contrary, to unload loaded models, call `AggregatedView#hide( bubble )`.